# Copy/Pastable Machzor

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, prayer-book, high-holidays

I've been looking for some time without success for a simple computer text copy of the machzorim for Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur. However, despite my inability to locate such a resource, I am not discouraged in regards to its existence. Does anyone have access to such a text?

It would ideally be CC-BY(-SA), with the correct text according to Nusach Ashkenaz and would include the piyutim (Daat.ac.IL has Sephard, but their Ashkenaz is in PDF with unusable OCR). Formatting would not be an issue, as this is for a personal typesetting project.

Comment: Wikitext (Hebrew) does not have it, before anyone else goes and checks.

Comment: Hi Noach - Hebrewbooks.org, I believ,e has a number of machzorim online. I know that you can download almost everything that they have into PDF format. The problem, of course, may be finding an accurate text conversion of the PDF into Hebrew text. That's a technical area that I'm not familiar with. I'd imagine that there is some way to do it. Before I bother some of my Israeli tecchie friends, give me an idea if this would do the trick for you, if it works?

Comment: @DanF, that's what prompted this question last year. I couldn't find an OCR'ed text which actually cut-and-pasted accurately.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you need it to be copy and pastable, as opposed to just printable? Please [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/60726/edit) to clarify.

Comment: @ezra Perhaps to easily be able to make adjustments to the Nusach

Comment: @ezra, is "this is for a personal typesetting project," not clear enough? As someone who uses InDesign (and knows how to make a photo-text pastiches) I can say that a simple, printable text won't work, as it creates several times more work than copy-paste-check nusach.

Answer (score 1):

[Sefaria](http://sefaria.org) has, as of recently, the [Metsudah](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075JKTNLS) Interlinear [Machzors](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LU54LY) available for bilingual browsing and download, licensed [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/):

- [Rosh Hashana](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Rosh_Hashanah_Ashkenaz_Linear?lang=bi)
- [Yom Kippur](https://www.sefaria.org/Machzor_Yom_Kippur_Ashkenaz_Linear?lang=bi)

I'm not sure how extensive the coverage of *piyutim* is.

Answer (score 0):

The only two for the Yamim Noraim that I'm aware of with multiple online versions, are listed below. Not the exact nusach you're after but the following are available:

- [Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel, nusach Ashkenaz in the minhag of Bad Homburg, Germany.](http://opensiddur.org/siddurim/ashkenaz/siddur-bnei-ashkenaz-a-german-rite-siddur-prepared-by-r-rallis-wiesenthal/) Collated by Rav Rallis Wiesenthal based on pre-Haskalah manuscripts. Online versions: XHTML, ODT, TXT and PDF.
- [The Authorised Daily Prayer Book of the United Hebrew Congregations of the British Empire.](https://archive.org/details/standardprayerbo00hagg) Nusach Ashkenaz, originally published under the authorization of Chief Rabbi Nathan Marcus Adler (based on *Seder Avodat Yisroel* by Isaac Seligman Baer, 1868). Hebrew and English text (translation by Rav Simeon Singer, 1890). Online versions: ABBYY GZ, Daisy, EPUB, Kindle, TXT, JP2 and PDF.

Comment: Thanks, Meir, but this isn't what I'm looking for. I certainly know of *Tefiloh Sefas Yisroel* and I often consult it, but the questions specifies that an acceptable answer would include the relevant piyutim.

Comment: Sorry Noach those are the only two I'm aware of :( Good luck in your search